# Confused on Indices, i think

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to produce a couple of simple crosstabs to produce a matrix (5*5), with decile values of a score on each column

To do this, I needed to merge three DataFrames together for the right fields to be in place (A to B on matchkey combo 1, AB to C on a different combo)

When I try to produce the deciles one works and one doesn't yet the code looks the same. (I am too new or stupid to understand the errors.)

---

```
all_merged_pre_matrix.columns['Decile4'] = pd.qcut(all_merged_pre_matrix['min_score'], 5,labels=False)
```

delivers an error:-

> ```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> ~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9232\653971323.py in <module>
> ----> 1 all_merged_pre_matrix.columns['Decile4'] = pd.qcut(all_merged_pre_matrix['min_score'], 5,labels=False)
> ```

> ```
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
>    5033     @final
>    5034     def __setitem__(self, key, value):
> -> 5035         raise TypeError("Index does not support mutable operations")
>    5036 
>    5037     def __getitem__(self, key):
>
> TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations
> ```

`min_score` comes from the `A` dataset.

---

```
all_merged_pre_matrix['Decile3'] = pd.qcut(all_merged_pre_matrix['app_score'], 5, labels=False)
```

works, `app_score` is from the `C` dataset.

---

I then want to produce two crosstabs of deciles (one for good, one for bad).

(Google suggests the mutable op problem relates to indices.)

Comment: Could you show the data type and structure of the 5x5 matrix

Comment: are you trying to add a new column 'Decile4' to the dataframe?

Comment: both score vars are int64, the matrix is decile 3 * Decile 4 *i want the volumes of accounts that fall in each cell)

Comment: decile4 is a new variable that doesn't create, with the error message above, whereas Decile 3 does create with no message (as stated both score vars are int64)

Comment: Does it work if you dont assign data but just execute the right hand side?

Comment: solved by doing the calc before the merge, i.e. the sledge hammer approach, but would like to understand what I did wrong or didn't do (so That i improve)

Comment: @MatthewFreeman the one that works isn't trying to set anything in `.columns`  - if you want to change either axis (index or columns), you generally have to set a whole new one [ or for a [Multi-Index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index), use one of the built-in methods specific to it ]

Comment: thanks for comments, always helpful